# How do I access Cost Allocation Tag data from AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a `Cost and Usage report` configured to delivery hourly data to an `S3` bucket. I query this using `AWS Athena`.

The config is attached below. It clearly states that `Cost Allocation Tags` are included in the report. However, this data doesn't show up in my `Athena` queries. Nor do I see any columns in the table that relates the `Cost Allocation Tags`.

I have `Cost Allocation Tags` activated and they correctly show up in `Cost Explorer`.

I browsed through the AWS documentation but couldn't find any mention of this.

So, how do I access Cost Allocation Tag data from AWS Athena?

[image: Cost and Usage report configuration]
[image: Cost Allocation Tags]
[image: Cost Explorer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just after posting the question I found the solution.

I created the `Cost Allocation Tags` later so they weren't included in the Athena table. I had to manually add these columns and it worked after that.

Here is the snippet that fixed it:

```
ALTER TABLE <reducted>.<reducted> ADD COLUMNS (resource_tags_aws_cloudformation_stack_id string, resource_tags_aws_cloudformation_stack_name string)
```

I managed to find the columns names from the `billing-create-table.sql` in the S3 bucket where the reports go.

Comment: Hey @daniel glad that you found the solution. Could you please share the Athena query which will get you TAG wise cost distribution?

Comment: This is the query I am using currently: 
```select year, 
  month, 
  line_item_product_code,
  product_location,
  line_item_resource_id,
  min(line_item_usage_start_date) as start_date,
  max(line_item_usage_end_date) as end_date,
  sum(line_item_blended_cost) as cost,
  resource_tags_user_XXX as xxx
from billing.billing
where year = '2021' and month in ('11')
group by year, month, line_item_product_code, product_location, line_item_resource_id, resource_tags_user_XXX
order by year, month asc```